# How do I get my page "About" to show up on my Wordpress site?

Tags: pages

I am currently using the Minnow theme on Wordpress. I have set my site to show latest posts from my blog, but I have also create a page called 'About'. This page doesn't show up on my site or in the navigation menu and I'm not quite sure how to get this to display.

Would appreciate any help I can get.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you added that page with a nav menu? And does your theme support nav menus?

Answer (score 0):

You need add page 'About' into Menus in WP. That show page 'About' on navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to dashboard
Then go to Appearance -> Menus. Now you have menu dashboard open.
Now create a menu by writing name of menu and click create.
After that add page to that menu by clicking check-box of page and then add. After adding Assign it to primary menu by clicking the check-box at bottom then save menu.

Also read [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org) documentation